# Why is antd select virtualization disabled when dropdownMatchSeleectWidth is false?

Tags: antd

I have a searchable select component where I'd like the dropdown menu width to be independent of the input width. There are around ~1000 items on the list.

When `dropdownMatchSelectWidth={false}` is set, the list takes almost 8 seconds to open. Without it, it opens instantly. I dove into the docs and found this is due to virtualization being disabled when that property is set. Is there a reason for this, and is there a workaround that anyone is aware of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, you can set a numeric static width for that property and that will preserve virtualization. This is most likely because virtualization requires a static size.